# How do I make this email me the referring URL

Tags: php, visitor-statistic

I have very very very basic knowledge of PHP and I need the following code which emails me everyone someone visits my page to also include in the message of the email the referring URL that landed the user on that page. That is it. I have tried a few things I read on stackoverflow but I couldnt.

Thank you!

```
    <?php
    // The message
    $message = "Client  has viewed the page";

    // In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

    // Send
    mail('myemail@mydomain.com', 'Client 126 Viewed Biz Landing', $message);

    // Redirect
    header('Location: http://dazogo.com');
    ?>
```

Comment: what is happening? any error?

Comment: I just get a blank page when I add anything. I may be adding it wrong Im not sure. I would really appreciate it if someone with knowledge would resend me the code with the right thing added in place.

Comment: try removing wordwrap

Comment: I got it thanks to someone else. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to the contents of the e-mail.

```
$message = "Client has viewed the page with referer " . preg_replace('_\s_m', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

The `preg_replace` part is for security, it will strip away all spaces (which should not be in a URL anyway).

Comment: Could you please do it? i already tried that and the page just goes blank.

Comment: Then you must enable error reporting, then you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: Unfortunate I have no knowledge of this stuff. I was just hoping to add the code and fix the problem. Thank you for helping though appreciate it.

Comment: You should teach yourself how to do this, otherwise you'll be back here in no-time with a similar problem. If you can debug these problems by yourself, you can work much faster.